# Linux kernel networking Ubuntu debug message not shown with printk/pr_debug?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, make, dmesg

I have recompiled the Linux kernel on Ubuntu and now upgraded to 4.17.6. I need to modify the TCP/IP stack parts, in specific one of the congestion control algorithms (eg. Vegas). After successful recompilation to 4.17.6, I tried to modify the code and only recompile relevant modules but can’t see any messages on the `dmesg`. I followed the following steps to test whether the `printk` and `pr_debug` works but none of them worked.

I added `#define DEBUG` on top of the modified files, then I added the following lines into desired functions `net/ipv4/ip_input.c` and `net/ipv4/ip_output.c`:

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "test:");
printk("test:");
pr_debug("test:");
```

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo make -j8 net
sudo make -j8 M=net
sudo make -j8 modules SUBDIRS=net
sudo make -j8 modules_install SUBDIRS=net
sudo reboot
```

After reboot I modified `printk` file to show all message levels by executing `echo 8 | sudo dd of=/proc/sys/kernel/printk`.  Then tried pinging from VM and to the VM and tried opening webpages.  Then, tried to see message by running `dmesg | grep test:`

But no messages are shown, where is the problem?